# Assigning to double underscore methods (__eq__, __lt__, __gt__)

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this example, I am trying to **assign** new `__eq__`, `__lt__` and `__gt__` methods and invoke them by comparing the object to the literal `3`. Why is `bar(...)` never called?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__eq__ = self.bar
        self.__lt__ = self.bar
        self.__gt__ = self.bar

    def bar(self, other):
        print("bar called.")

a = Foo()
a == 3
a < 3
a > 3
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176343/489345) I found the hint `you can't assign new __eq__ to the object`. I can't find any official source for this statement though.

Any hints and help is appreciated!

*Edit: I am aware that there is the option of defining `__eq__` in the object itself, but this questions is specifically about assigning it after instance creation.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Special Method Lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup):

> implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.

If the goal is to use `bar` for comparisons, assign it at the class level, not per instance (which will also save memory by not bloating the per instance attribute dictionary):

```
class Foo:
    def bar(...):
        ...
    __eq__ = __lt__ = __gt__ = bar
```

Comment: I am not sure why I am being downvoted, I don't think it's such a trivial question. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: I suspect because this sort of question gets asked a lot (I basically copied my answer from a comment I made on a similar question about `__call__`). I didn't downvote, but people often downvote what they view as redundant questions.

Comment: Obviously I tried searching, but I didn't find any information on it on SO. But true, I didn't think of trying to assign `__call__`, maybe I could have found more info.

Comment: If you need to be able to override per instance, then define some other method (e.g. `_realeq`) and define `__eq__` (at class level) to call it. You can then assign instances their own `_realeq` which, not being a special method, will be called as you expect.

Comment: I was researching for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501397/object-that-raises-exception-when-used-in-any-way) when I stumbled about this problem. I tried replacing all the methods listed by `dir(...)` on an instance, but apparently the underscore methods failed.